# DB2 JDBC connection to a schema in IASP

Tags: jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I have a JDBC receiver adapter in PI 7.1 running on i5/OS.

I deployed the DB2 driver with JSPM and it's working fine on a schema who is NOT in the independent auxiliary storage pool (IASP)

When I try to access my schema in the IASP the Adapter cannot establish a connection. Any idea if I need to modify my connection url, the driver, security, ?

thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 1):

URL to the Database need to be changed accordingly to the IASP.

•   Toolbox driver: jdbc:as400://;rdbname=;;
•   Native driver: jdbc:db2iSeries:;;